# Injecting state into UITabBarController child controllers

Tags: ios, dependency-injection, tabs, uitabbarcontroller

How do I inject state into a viewcontroller that is shown as a child of a UITabBarController?  I have two sibling tabs that are both showing information for a selected day.  It's possible to change what day is selected in either the TextView tab or the GraphView tab, and I want both tabs to keep in sync so I don't confuse the user.

One reasonably simple way would be to declare a global state variable to hold currentDate, and have each tab viewcontroller check currentDate in -viewWillAppear:.

But all the advice says not to do globals (or equivalents, like shared singletons or properties on the application delegate, whatever).  Instead you're supposed to do dependency injection so that each controller gets a reference to the shared state object.  But when/how do you do this?  UITabBarController normally doesn't load its tab views until the user requests to see them. I don't think I want to pre-load everything in -application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:, slowing down application launch.   But UITabBarController doesn't seem to provide any kind of -tabWillAppear event to hook into, so I seem to be stuck with keeping currentDate in a global.

Am I missing something?  Thanks.